# Servlet should not process any new request until it completes processing of previous request

Tags: servlets, filter

I have a web application that performs just one heavy process.Now suppose any user has send a request, and servlet is processing (This processing may take about an hour). if the same user hits the link again knowingly or unknowingly before the previous request is completed. The app should not allow it and should display a message saying, we are already processing your previous request.

for example- User hits the link - www.example.com/myApp/saw.dll and servlet is processing. now before the processing finished, same user hits the same link again. I do not want the request to be processed again and just display a message that we are processing.

How to restrict the servlet from processing any new request from the same user if it is already processing previous request (from the same user)?

Hope my question is clear. Appreciate your valuable suggestion.

Comment: Actually, there is no question at all in what you posted.

Comment: oops. i aplologize. Just to add more-  How to implement the situation explained above ??
How to restrict the servlet from processing any new request from the same if it is already processing previous request ?

Thanks